# Changing the width of a textbox in TikZ horizontal graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I'm a beginner at Ti*k*Z, but I need a parent-child horizontal graph.
My problem is that the boxes are a set width and I don't know how to change it.

Looking through answers to similar questions I thought changing

```
[grow'=right,level distance=1.25in,sibling distance=.15in, scale=0.80]
```

to

```
[grow'=right,level distance=1.25in,sibling distance=.15in, scale=0.80, text width=4.25in]
```

should do the trick, but it doesn't.

So, basically, how do you change the text width of the text boxes?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,level distance=2.25in,sibling distance=.15in, scale=0.80]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw, edge from parent fork right},
         every tree node/.style=
            {draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in,align=center}}
\Tree 
    [. {Very long text for the parent node} 
        [.{The first child} ]
        [.{The second child with extra baggage}
                [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much} ]
        ] 
        [.{Third child will probably also have baggage} ]
        [.{But this is just an example} ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Try `text width=2in`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work :( (Would the reasoning be that the text width does not take decimals?)

Comment: Strange, compiling with pdflatex on MikTeX works with TikZ 3.1.4 as well as TikZ 3.1.5a. What is your version of Tikz? Which engine do you compile with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text with an arbitrary `\node` command after which the full range of node commands comes into play. For example, you can change the width of the second last box to achieve:

[image]

with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,level distance=2.25in,sibling distance=.15in, scale=0.80]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
            {thick, draw, edge from parent fork right},
         every tree node/.style=
            {draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in,align=center}}
\Tree
    [. {Very long text for the parent node}
        [.{The first child} ]
        [.{The second child with extra baggage}
                [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much } ]
            [.{A lot of text describing this second child, really a lot of text, about this much} ]
        ]
        [.\node[minimum width=45mm, fill=blue!10]{Third child will probably also have baggage}; ]
        [.{But this is just an example} ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that as you have set `minimum width=1in,text width=1in` in the table specifications at the top of the diagram that the `text width` is still set to `1in` and so in unchanged in this example.

Comment: Thank you! my question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

With `forest`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, font=\small, 
    text centered,
% tree    
    grow' = east,
    forked edge,
    l sep=8mm,
 fork sep=4mm,
%
    where level={2}{text width=12em}{text width=8em},
    where level={1}{s sep=2mm}{s sep=7mm},
            }
% diagram
[Very long text for the parent node, calign=edge midpoint
    [The first child]
    [The second child with extra baggage, calign=edge midpoint
        [{A lot of text describing this second child,
          really a lot of text, about this much}]
        [{A lot of text describing this second child,
          really a lot of text, about this much}]
        [{A lot of text describing this second child,
          really a lot of text, about this much}]
        [{A lot of text describing this second child,
          really a lot of text, about this much}]
    ]
    [Third child will probably also have baggage]
    [But this is just an example]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]